# Variance of event count in a two-state Markov Modulated Poisson Process (2-MMPP) during a given time period

Tags: markov-process, poisson-process

I have a two-state Markov Modulated Poisson Process (2-MMPP). It's a two-state continuous time Markov process, with $\mu_{12}$ the switching rate from state 1 to state 2 ; $\mu_{21}$ the switching rate from state 2 to state 1. In state 1, events happen as a Poisson process of rate $\lambda_1$. In state 2, events happen as a Poisson process of rate $\lambda_2$. [Here's a representation of the 2-MMPP](https://mermaid.ink/img/pako:eNqNUDsOwjAMvYrlmQ7JmIGJkQHRNUvUuDRSm6DELUKIYzGxcQDORPpBMDDgxfZ7fs-WL1gFS6gwsWHaOHOIpisGqT3ksC5SxS542O5nZBoDjeWUhUYwCUrxi5QLuXiVAopinVsFj5t4g3IGxQjKxcaHrG6pZgj1RO2CSykfcYyhopTg5LgBGsgzxHHT8_6tjO7QzFL5jzRfgivsKHbG2fyIy2ilkRvqSKPKpaXa9C1r1P6aR03PoTz7ChXHnlbYH-3ndahq0ya6vgAFt3BT?type=png).

I'm observing the process during a duration $T$. **I'm trying to find out the  variance of the number of events $N_T$ observed during this duration.**

Here's what I have so far:

- The steady-state vector is  $\Pi = \begin{pmatrix} \pi_1 & \pi_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  \frac{\mu_{21}}{\mu_{12} + \mu_{21}} & \frac{\mu_{12}}{\mu_{12} + \mu_{21}}\end{pmatrix}$. So, on average, the system is in state 1 for a duration of $\pi_1 \times T$ during $T$.
- "*the number of points in a region of finite size is a random variable with a Poisson distribution*" ([Wikipedia page for Poisson point processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process)).

  - This means that the mean number of events in each state is the event rate. Therefore, the mean number of events can be calculated as: $\mathbb{E}[N_T] = \pi_1 \lambda_1 + \pi_2 \lambda_2$
  - This also means that the variance of the numbers of events in each state is the event rate. If we're in state 1 during the entire duration of $T$, the variance is $Var(N_T | \text{{In state 1 during $T$}}) = \lambda_1$

What I can't figure out now is **how do I calculate the variance of the time spent in each state while I observe the process?**

Once I find that, I think I'll manage to get my final result $Var(N_T)$ using conditional variance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I found the answer** in this paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/0305-0548(92)90014-V

With the following notations, as used in the paper:

- $n(t)$ the number of events during time interval $(0,t]$
- $s_i$ the random variable of the time spent in state $i$ before there is a switch
- $Z_{it}$ the random variable of the time spent in state $i$ during $(0,t]$

In this paper, the variance of the time spent in each state $\mathbb{V}(Z_{it})$ is presented in the 4th equation. To get there, they assume that $s_1$ and $s_2$ have finite means and variances. They also use properties of renewal processes, described by Cox (*D. R. Cox, Renewal Theory. Methuen, London (1962) - p.101*), but I could not get an access to this book to dig deeper there. They find:

$$
\mathbb{V}[Z_{it}] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[s_1]^2 \mathbb{V}[s_2] + \mathbb{E}[s_2]^2 \mathbb{V}[s_1]}{\left( \mathbb{E}[s_1] + \mathbb{E}[s_2] \right)^3} \times t + o(1)
$$

The 6th equation gives the variance of the number of events happening during $T$ while in state $i$, which they note $Y_{it}$.

$$
\mathbb{V}[Y_{it}] =  \mathbb{E} \left[ \mathbb{V} \left[ \frac{n(t)}{Z_{it}} \right] \right] + \mathbb{V} \left[ \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{n(t)}{Z_{it}} \right] \right] 
= \mathbb{E} [Z_{it}] \lambda_i + \mathbb{V}[Z_{it}] \lambda_i^2
$$

To get to what I wanted in the end, which is the the variance of the total number of events happening during $T$, since $Y_{1t}$ and $Y_{2t}$ are independant, I had $\mathbb{V}[Y_{1t} + Y_{2t}] = \mathbb{V}[Y_{1t}] + \mathbb{V}[Y_{2t}]$ .

Comment: You're right @ronno, I edited my answer, adding the relevant informations.